# Parsing <br> tags with beautifulsoup

Tags: html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, tags, web-crawler

I am crawling a website and the structure of 
 tags is :

```
<div class="content"
    <p> 
        "C Space"
        <br>
        "802 white avenue"
        <br>
        "xyz 123"
        <br>
        "Lima"
    </p>
```

When I use beautifulsoup to get the text using the following command:

```
html=urlopen("something")
bsObj = BeautifulSoup(html,"html5lib")
templist = bsObj.find("div",{"class":"content"})
print(templist.get_text())
```

I get the following output:
C Space802 white avenuexyz 123Lima

whereas I want the output to be : C Space 802 white avenue xyz 123 Lima.

How can I add an extra whitespace when getting data from subsequent br tags?

Thanks

Answer (score 9):

You can play around with the [`.get_text()`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#get-text) arguments:

```
In [4]: elm = soup.select_one(".content")

In [5]: print(elm.get_text(strip=True, separator=" "))
"C Space" "802 white avenue" "xyz 123" "Lima"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `split` and `join` here :

```
>>> ' '.join(templist.get_text().split())
'"C Space" "802 white avenue" "xyz 123" "Lima"'
```